How to dissolve and multipart to singlepart in Microsoft SQL Server
I have a table of partly overlapping multipolygons.
I need to dissolve the overlaps so the polygons arent overlapping.
If it were PostGIS I would ST_UNION and then ST_DUMP.
Test data:
with three_polygons as (
SELECT 1 as id, geometry::STGeomFromText('MultiPolygon (((616674 7018275, 616674 7020200, 618719 7020200, 618719 7018275, 616674 7018275)))', 3006) as geom
union all
SELECT 2 as id, geometry::STGeomFromText('MultiPolygon (((617596 7017373, 617596 7019138, 619361 7019138, 619361 7017373, 617596 7017373)))', 3006) as geom
union all
SELECT 3 as id, geometry::STGeomFromText('MultiPolygon (((616934 7020662, 616934 7021524, 618458 7021524, 618458 7020662, 616934 7020662)))', 3006) as geom
)
select * from three_polygons


I have figured out how to dissolve into one multipolygon:
select geometry::UnionAggregate(geom)
from three_polygons


But how can I explode the multipolygon into the individual parts? With this I can extract each part but I have to manually specify each part number..
select geometry::UnionAggregate(geom).STGeometryN(1) from three_polygons

